# Team Foundation Server: Getting the Changeset Id from PolicyBase object

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, tfs

I'm writing a custom check-in policy in Visual Studio 2010 using C#. I've extended the class PolicyBase and overriden the Evaluate() method so that I can check the user's check-in comment contains specific information. I'm getting the user's check-in comment using this.PendingCheckin.PendingChanges.Comment

What I would like to be able to do is pull out the changeset number that will be assigned to the check-in. Where and how would I get this number?

I'm guessing the Evaluate method is the wrong place because the changeset has been committed at that point and thus the changeset number cannot be determined.

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this with any degree of certainty with a check-in policy, as they are only evaluated **pre-checkin**.  The server assigns you the changeset when you do the checkin.

You could try to deduce the next changeset number by querying history on $/ (with a limit of 1 history item returned).  But obviously you will have a race condition if you depend on this value - someone could easily beat you to the next checkin, thus taking the number you think will be next.

That said, you can get data about check-ins *outside of the check-in policy framework*.  You can either [hook up a `CommitCheckin` event to an instance of `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionControlServer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.versioncontrolserver.commitcheckin%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), or you can hook up [an alert that will notify you when a check-in occurs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc507647.aspx).

Comment: That degree of uncertainty would make it unsuitable for my purpose. I find it bizarre that there's no way to obtain this using a check-in policy or some other technique.

Comment: Why is it bizarre?  It's **completely unknowable**.  Check-in policies run - literally - at the moment you make a pending change and after.  They aren't only evaluated at the moment before you do a check-in.  (And even if they were, they **still** couldn't know the changeset number with any degree of certainty, because there's still a race condition, just one with a smaller window.)

Comment: I understand that the Evaluate method only gets called before the check-in but I would have assumed there would be some other method exposed when the check-in has occurred, thus giving you the guaranteed changeset number. The fact that this hook isn't present is what I find bizarre.

Comment: I see - this isn't part of the check-in policy API, but you can listen for TFS events to get the changeset data after the changeset is committed.  I edited the above answer with pointers to some documentation that may assist.

Comment: Top stuff, thanks for the reply and extra information. (Sorry, was diverted onto another task for a while so just got back onto this.)